# Site Actions button is disabled

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint 2007 site where the Site Actions button is disabled only in IE. When a user first arrives to the page the Site Actions button works,but when he/she refreshes the page the Site Actions button is disabled, but if he/she does a refresh for the third time the Site Actions button works again? Any ideas...

UPDATE
I am using jQuery-1.6. What I is that once I take that reference out I no longer get error.

Comment: May be you are making some jQuery code to hide or modify some html block and it happens that site action container (may be `div`) included in the hidden part!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to debig this is to use Web Developer Tool bar in IE 8+ and then check the style for "Site Actions". It will give you some ideas about what is happening.